# What is the advantage of using vector<char> as input buffer over char array?

Tags: c++, networking

I am working on a network programming and I have seen people using vector as the input buffer for socket instead of char array.

I was wondering what it the advantage of doing this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: i'm like the kind of person that does so. if you've ever worked with java nio and familiar with IoBuffer, you'll see why vector<char> is a handy alternative in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `vector<char>` is essentially just a managed character array.

So you can write:

```
{
    vector<char> buf(4096);
    ...
    int result = recv(fd, &buf[received_so_far], buf.size() - received_so_far);
    ...
}
```

The vector "knows" its size, so you can use `buf.size()` everywhere and never have to worry about overrunning your buffer.  You can also change the size in the declaration and have it take effect everywhere without any messy #defines.

This use of `buf` will allocate the underlying array on the heap, and it will free it automatically when `buf` goes out of scope, no matter how that happens (e.g. exceptions or early return).  So you get the nice semantics of stack allocation while still keeping large objects on the heap.

You can use `buf.swap()` to "hand ownership" of the underlying character array to another `vector<char>` very efficiently.  (This is a good idea for network traffic...  Modern networks are fast.  The last thing you want to do is to create yet another copy of every byte you receive from the network.)  And you still do not have to worry about explicitly freeing the memory.

Those are the big advantages that come to mind off the top of my head for this particular application.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. The way I copied the vector vector<char> copyVector(m_vbuffer); Should I do swap instead of copy? What is advantage of swap over copy?

Comment: In this case there is not much advantage for swap. If a vector did not default-initialize its contents then there would be a benefit. But it does, and writing zeros into memory takes just as much time as copying to another vector.

Comment: @Zan: There is an advantage if you swap with a zero-size vector, which is actually what I had in mind.

Comment: @Nemo: But a C library function like `recv` needs an allocated buffer. It doesn't know how to expand a vector.

Comment: @Zan: Yes, what I meant is that you can call `recv` to get the next block of data, then hand it off to another piece of your code without copying.

Comment: @Nemo: Before you can call `recv` you must `resize` your vector, which causes the vector to default-construct (zero-fill in this case) the elements.

Comment: @Zan: True, but if the vector is small (as it should be), the zeroed elements will be in L1 cache when `recv` overwrites them.  (Assuming data is arriving fast from the network; else why care about performance?)  So only one write will actually hit the memory bus.  At least, this was my experience when I benchmarked a few approaches on a 10GbE network.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13695/discussion-between-zan-lynx-and-nemo)

Comment: I was using this and it was triggering gcc's stack smashing detection. I went back to using char buf[4096]. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

using vector is:

- easy to grow-up space of memory.
- easy to make copy of datas.
- easy to free.

Answer (score 3):

My main reason:

- Its Exception Safe.

  - No matter what goes wrong the vector will not leak memory.

Comment: Unless vector is allocated on heap!

Comment: @Ajay: No such thing as a heap in C++ context. What you really mean is "Dynamic Storage Duration" object. And it not relevant to the question as any "Dynamic Storage Duration" objects should be wrapped in some form of smart pointer and the point of the vector is to replace "Dynamic Storage Duration" arrays of char as the data area is dynamically allocated.

Comment: I just mentioned that if vector<T> itself is stored in heap, and that heap-memory isn't freed, the vector has implicitly leaked memory. No, not the fault of vector. Even memory leak detection tools won't blame vector, but the location where vector was allocated on heap. :)

Comment: @Ajay. As I said. There is no such things as a heap. "Dynamic Storage Duration Object"

Answer (score 1):

`vector` can be easily resized and allows convenient partial deletion of data - that's big advantage. In many cases having a fixed size array is inconvenient - for example you will read blocks of data and process received data in chunks smaller than received chunks. Then you want to know the actual amount of data left - that will be `vector.size()` and you won't have to store it in a separate variable and when you delete part of the data `vector` will move the remaining for you.

Comment: Is `size()` constant time?  If so, then this can also be advantageous to a naked (null terminated) char array.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: You often manipulate data that is not null terminated in the first place.

Comment: "Deleting part of the data" is a horrible idea with `vector`, actually.  It does work, but it is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @Nemo: It's not the most efficient operation, but if you delete a huge part of a rather small vector it isn't a big problem.

Comment: But it does make _yet another_ copy of at least some of the data.  I agree it depends on your application.  But if you are pushing any non-trivial amount of data over a modern network, you really cannot afford to be so lazy about data movement in memory...  I did not downvote you, because you are not wrong.  But I do think you are giving poor advice for anything other than "toy" applications.

Comment: @Nemo: Well, suppose you have a vector with 200 elements and you iterate over them and decide that the first 121 elements form a string - how would you extract that string?

Comment: If possible, you don't...  You keep a set of offsets into the vector and use those.  It is definitely extra accounting.  But then, I am used to pushing large amounts of data across a fast network.  If your application is not so demanding, then just letting the vector do the work is OK.  My use of "toy" was perhaps too extreme :-).

Comment: @Nemo: I see. My experience was to build a POP3 client - it has been shipping within a commercial application for years already and noone has yet complained about performance. Of course I realize that some server applications can have other usage patterns.

Comment: By "large amounts of data" I mean hundreds of gigabytes per hour; by "fast network" I mean 10GbE...  I have become allergic to unnecessary data copying.

Answer (score 0):

If you've ever programmed network applications in Java, you are likely to be familiar with [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [IoBuffer](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/mina/mina-core/2.0.1/mina-core-2.0.1-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/mina/core/buffer/IoBuffer.html). The two classes made buffer handling significantly easier with pretty easy and intuitive interface.

In the world of C++, very fortunately, with the standard vector class everything provided by this two class is what you can use. Since vector can dynamically grow, it's even more powerful than ByteBuffer and IoBuffer. Just write your code and you'll find everything you would expect in a byte buffer wrapper is just there.

Some obvious advantage:

- Preallocate memory with vector::reserve
- Remember buffer position with vector::size
- Grow/clear buffer with vector::resize
- Convert to C buffer with &your_vector[0]
- Transfer buffer ownership with vector::swap
- ... and more to be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

One main difference between `std::vector<char> buffer(SIZE)` and `std::array<char, SIZE> buffer` is the placement of the `SIZE` argument: For `vector`, you only need to know the size at runtime, and you can even change the size, if needed. For `array`, `SIZE` is a template parameter, so you need to know it already at compile time and it stays fixed until you recompile. So, basically `std::array` is just a wrapper around C style arrays `char buffer[SIZE]`. While since the C++14 standard, C style arrays may be dynamically sized in C++, `std::array` is always statically sized. However, be aware, that C style arrays are usually allocated on the stack, and that stack space is limited in most implementations.

The next difference is, that `std::vector` performs value-initialization on its elements, which usually means setting them to zero (unless you override that with a custom constructor), while `std::array` and C style arrays leave their content uninitialized.

Therefore:

- If you need a buffer of a known fixed size, if that size doesn't exceed a few kilobytes, AND if the contents of that buffer are going to be properly written by the application, use `std::array` or a C style array. This is the faster solution.
- Otherwise, use `std::vector`. This is the safer solution.